# how to filter and validate select option in form using PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation, select, dropdown

```php
$batch = htmlentities($_POST['batch']);
if($batch === 'NULL'){
echo "Batch Failed";
} else {
echo "$bacth";
}
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
         <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></span>
         <select class="form-control" name="batch" id="select">
            <option selected disabled>Batch Preference</option>
            <option value="Weekends">Weekends</option>
            <option value="Holidays">Holidays</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How to select those select options in form using php, how i can validate them...

Thank You

Comment: This 2 articles might help you 1. https://www.sitepoint.com/form-validation-with-php/    
2. https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-filters.php

Comment: Your question is not clear , kindly explain what do you mean by validate them , also post content of $batch

Comment: batch i am just taking those values options, it was just variable, my problem is How i can filter select options in php...
by selecting those name, how i can select options of value and how i can filter them, to send mail...